# SmartGWT Layout Order Styles

Tags: java, css, smartgwt

I have a SmartGWT HLayout and I want it to have a red border at its bottom. How should I achive it? The following code gives a red border, but it is applied to all sides. Need help.

```
    HLayout headerSection = new HLayout();
    headerSection.setHeight("7%");
    headerSection.setWidth100();
    headerSection.setBorder("5px solid #C90909;");
```